# How to unpack the data in the sublists into one list?

Tags: python

Consider following code:

```
string = "ABCD"
variations = [list(itertools.combinations(string,x)) for x in range(1,5)]
variations
```

It produces following output:

```
[[('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',)],
 [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')],
 [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D')],
 [('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]]
```

But the output I would like is:

```
[('A',),
 ('B',),
 ('C',),
 ('D',),
 ('A', 'B'),
 ('A', 'C'),
 ('A', 'D'),
 ('B', 'C'),
 ('B', 'D'),
 ('C', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C'),
 ('A', 'B', 'D'),
 ('A', 'C', 'D'),
 ('B', 'C', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]
```

In other words, I want to unpack all the data in the sublists into one list (in the shortest way possible)

I've tried to use asterisk:

```
string = "ABCD" 
variations = [*list(itertools.combinations(string,x)) for x in range(1,5)]
```

But it throws following error:

> SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension

What should I do? (Again, I would like to keep things concise)

Comment: Did you know this operation is often called 'flatten'?  (flatmap, join, ...)

Answer (score 3):

Just add another `for` to your list comprehension that loops over the `combinations`:

```
variations = [y for x in range(1, 5) for y in itertools.combinations(string, x)]
print(variations)
```

Output:

```
[('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a nested iteration inside the list comprehension. Something like this:

```
[y for x in range(1,5) for y in itertools.combinations(string, x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`variations = [e  for x in range(1,5) for e in (itertools.combinations(string,x)) ]`